# Primefaces autocomplete rendered in a wrong place

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I am using PrimeFaces 4.0, JSF2, jBoss EAP 6.1, Bootsrtap 3. I've got two places in my project where I use `<p:autocomplete>`, one renders OK the other does not. Suggestion part of auto complete should appear inside a `<div>` container at the bottom of the page:

```
<div id="searchForm:j_id_8t_5k_panel" class="ui-autocomplete-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-helper-hidden ui-shadow"></div>
```

but my buggy one renders in the same place where `<p:autocomplete>` tag should be, it actually replaces input with plain `<ul>` with suggestions that you can not click.

[image: before]

[image: after]

I am using proper JSF tags like `<h:body>` etc.

My autocomplete component:

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{search.item}" completeMethod="#{search.autocomplete}"
var="item" itemLabel="#{item.label}" itemValue="#{item}" converter="objectConverter"  
forceSelection="true" minQueryLength="3" scrollHeight="200" 
global="false" />
```

Anyone had a similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of my problem was that I've put my `<p:autocomplete>` inside a `<p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">`. After removing autoUpdate everything works fine! Don't really know why it should break an autocomplete element, but it does. Hope it helps someone.